# Flattening binary tree to array: Is there a way to find a node's index in the array when traversing depth-first?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-tree

I want to flatten a binary tree like

```
  2
 / \
1   4
   / \
  3   7
```

to an array like

```
{2, 1, 4, null, null, 3, 7}
```

This is pretty common in my understanding, perhaps even canonical.

I know that if I traverse the tree breadth-first (BFS), say, using a queue to tack on nodes to visit as I come across them, then building such an array is automatic—BFS ordering is exactly the ordering of the array.

But I wondered if there was a way to build the array while traversing depth-first (DFS).

I came up with one scheme that didn't quite work:

1. While traversing recursively, keep track of the *level* you're on (`L`), as well as the number of times you went *right* (`R`).
2. Then the index is given by the formula, `(2^L)-1+R`.

Unfortunately, this failed because the *order* in which left and right "turns" are made, matter.

Is there a different state that can be tracked to yield the index efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're using zero-based indexing, then the nodes at depth *d* (0 for the root, 1 for the root's direct children, etc.) start at index 2<sup>*d*</sup>−1.

Within the "row" of nodes at a given depth, we can think of each "descend into left child" and "descend into right child" step as a bit: left = 0 (first half), right = 1 (second half). For example, if we start at the root node and go left–left–right, then we'll end up at position 001<sub>2</sub> in the row of depth 3, whereas if we start at the root node and go right–right–left, then we'll end up at position 110<sub>2</sub> in that row.

We can then just add the start-index of the row to the position within the row to get the overall index.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
get_index(path):
    row_start := 0
    position_in_row := 0
    for element in path:
        row_start := 2 * row_start + 1
        position_in_row := 2 * position_in_row
        if element is 'RIGHT':
            position_in_row := position_in_row + 1
    return row_start + position_in_row
```

If we're using one-based indexing, then change `row_start := 0` to `row_start := 1` and `row_start := 2 * row_start + 1` to `row_start := 2 * row_start`.

Comment: Ah, so I needed to use both Left and Right decisions, representing as 0 or 1 respectively, starting with the Most Significant Bit and then lesser significant ones. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give me a hint why is this true "If we're using zero-based indexing, then the nodes at depth d (0 for the root, 1 for the root's direct children, etc.) start at index 2d−1."?

Comment: Also, am I right that something is wrong in your pseudocode? F.e. the result of get_index("leftt_child_of_the_root") is -1, right?

Comment: @datjko: For your second question: you are quite right, I should have had `+ 1` rather than `- 1`. Now fixed, thanks!

Comment: @datjko: For your first question: there's 1 root node (depth = 0), it has 2 child nodes (depth = 1), they have a total of 4 child nodes (depth = 2), etc. So there are 2^d nodes at each depth, meaning that there are 2^(d+1)-1 nodes in depths 0 through d, meaning that the first node at depth d+1 starts at position 2^(d+1)-1. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ruakh: It make sense only under assumption that your binary tree is full. F.e. it's not true for the binary tree example in this question, right?

Comment: @ruakh sorry, I meant it's not true for the binary tree if you add one more fork at the node 7 in the in the tree example in the question (that's the tree like 2->(1, 4->(3, 7->(6, 8))) ).

Comment: @datjko: The OP shows a tree that's not full, but that's *treated* as full (for arrayification purposes) by filling in `null` for nodes that don't exist. (As I think you realize, such a filling-in approach is necessary if you want to use pure DFS, since otherwise the number of nodes at level *d* on a not-yet-traversed branch will affect the placement of any node at level *d*+1.)

Comment: @ruakh I understand how "arrayification" works for *complete* binary trees. It does not require the tree to be *full* for that. so, you mean your solution is applicable only for *full* binary trees and if a binary tree is complete but not full you suggest to fill in all missing subtrees with nulls on all layers? It does not look like a solution for this task in question, does it?

Comment: @datjko: Re: "if a binary tree is complete but not full you suggest to fill in all missing subtrees with nulls on all layers? It does not look like a solution for this task in question, does it?": *I'm* not suggesting doing that; rather, I interpret the *OP* as doing that. You're welcome to disagree, but since (s)he accepted my answer, I think my interpretation is borne out.

Comment: @ruakh I think it must be explicitly mentioned in your solution that it's applicable only to the case of *complete* binary trees (sorry, ever confuse the full and complete in binary trees; now did it again in my previous comment, argh!) as other people may think they found a generic solution for the task here. For full binary trees your solution is kind of obvious. Downvoted.

Comment: @datjko: Have a nice day.